# Antiword with UTF-8 in python

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding

This is my code :

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
cmd = ['antiword', 'tbhocbong151.doc']
p = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
print(stdout.decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
```

I have content in file word like this : `"Chào bạn"`

but when I generated output is: `"Ch?o b?n"`

How can I fix it to output like input ? 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the problem is that the locale is not properly set when `antiword` is running. Try this:

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
myenv = dict(os.environ)
if 'LC_ALL' in myenv:
    del myenv['LC_ALL']
myenv['LANG'] = 'en_US.UTF-8'
cmd = ['antiword', 'tbhocbong151.doc']
p = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, env=myenv)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
print(stdout.decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
```

If that doesn't work, try setting the `LANG` env variable in your shell before running your python program; e.g. by doing:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```